# PrepareForSegue is too fast for my other functions, and variables aren't updating in time?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a `FIRSTViewController` that has a button. The button has an IBAction function, in which it calls `CLGeocoder()`. The button is also a segue to a SECONDViewController.

The CLGeocoder inside the IBAction updates two variables, and those variables are passed in the prepareForSegue function.

However, since `CLGeocoder` acts asynchronously, it is too slow to update the variables before the segue occurs, and thus, the incorrect variables are being passed to the `SECONDViewController`. How could I fix this?

Here's the code in my IBAction method:

```
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(userInputText!) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if let firstPlacemark = placemarks?[0] {
                self.searchLatitude = "\(firstPlacemark.location!.coordinate.latitude)"
                self.searchLongitude = "\(firstPlacemark.location!.coordinate.longitude)"
                self.addressLoaded = true
            } else {
                //implement error pop up
                print("error")
            }
        }
```

Comment: should probably segue first, then in the viewDidLoad fire off the `CLGeocoder()` and show activity indicators while its waiting to finish, then when the `CLGeocoder()` completes, update the variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the `CLGeocoder` instance methods accept a `completionHandler` parameter. Try to call the `performSegue` from it

**EDIT**: this is an example

```
@IBAction private func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton?) {

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(
        "Your address string") { (let placeMarks, let error) in

            if let error = error {

                // handle the error

            } else if let placemarks = placeMarks {

                // Do whatever with the placemarks
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(
                    "Segue identifier",
                    sender: sender
                )
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some guidance, no clue what performSegue or how to use completionhandler

Comment: > call `performSegue` _from_ it ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused how performSegue or prepareforSegue work, and how they are called? How would you call prepareforSegue inside another method :3

Comment: @Waffles I added an example

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier` will call `prepareForSegue` after it's called, so you can do it anyway. Look here for detailed informations: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not use segue. You can simply instantiate the SecondViewController manually like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewControllerIdentifier") as! SecondViewController
```

And then you can do:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(userInputText!) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
    if let firstPlacemark = placemarks?[0] {
        self.searchLatitude = "\(firstPlacemark.location!.coordinate.latitude)"
        self.searchLongitude = "\(firstPlacemark.location!.coordinate.longitude)"
        self.addressLoaded = true

        //now present viewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        //implement error pop up
        print("error")
    }
}
```

You must set the identifier of the viewController in order to instantiate it: in order to do this open your storyboard and select your viewController, then open the inspector and set the id.